# Changing outputs into tuple [python]

Tags: python, tuples

```
def a_function(n, a, b, c):
    if n == 1:
        print((a,b))
else:
    a_function(n-1, a, c, b)
    print((a,b))
    a_function(n-1, c, b, a)    

a_function(3, 1, 2, 3)
```

How to make the function to return a tuple instead of output above?

(something like:((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2)) )

Comment: Kindly fix the indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return a tuple of tuple, and keep concatenating them as you return from the recursive calls . Example -

```
def a_function(n, a, b, c):
    if n == 1:
        return ((a,b),)
    else:
        x = a_function(n-1, a, c, b)
        return x + ((a,b),) + a_function(n-1, c, b, a)
```

Demo -

```
>>> def a_function(n, a, b, c):
...     if n == 1:
...         return ((a,b),)
...     else:
...         x = a_function(n-1, a, c, b)
...         return x + ((a,b),) + a_function(n-1, c, b, a)
...
...
>>> a_function(3, 1, 2, 3)
((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `yield`:

```
def gx(n, a, b, c):
    if n == 1:
        yield a, b
    else:
        for sub in gx(n - 1, a, c, b):
            yield sub
        yield a, b
        for sub in gx(n - 1, c, b, a):
            yield sub

print tuple(gx(3, 1, 2, 3))

((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried with another approach.

```
    lis=[]
    def a_function(n, a, b, c):
        if n == 1:
            lis.append((a,b))
        else:
            a_function(n-1, a, c, b)
            lis.append((a,b))
            a_function(n-1, c, b, a)

    a_function(3, 1, 2, 3)
    print tuple(lis)
```